# How to extract only 7 characters using grep

Tags: command-line, text-processing, grep, regex

I am using a regular expression with `grep`. I want to extract exactly 7 character passwords, but I am getting 7 and more than 7 characters as a result.

```
grep '[a-zA-Z0-9]\{7\}' /usr/share/wordlists/rockyou.txt

grep '[a-zA-Z0-9]\{7,7\}' /usr/share/wordlists/rockyou.txt
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use extended grep:

```
grep  -E '^[a-zA-Z0-9]{7}$' /usr/share/wordlists/rockyou.txt
```

or your own version like:

```
grep '^[a-zA-Z0-9]\{7\}$' /usr/share/wordlists/rockyou.txt
```

or even:

```
egrep '^.{7}$' /usr/share/wordlists/rockyou.txt
```

Answer (score 2):

Any line that contains more than 7 characters also contains a substring of 7 characters (which will match your expression).

You can force only complete matches by *anchoring* the expression to the start and end of the line:

```
grep '^[a-zA-Z0-9]\{7\}$' /usr/share/wordlists/rockyou.txt
```

or specify whole-line matching using the `-x` option

```
grep -x '[a-zA-Z0-9]\{7\}' /usr/share/wordlists/rockyou.txt
```

From `man grep`:

```
-x, --line-regexp
       Select  only  those  matches  that exactly match the whole line.
       For a regular expression pattern, this  is  like  parenthesizing
       the pattern and then surrounding it with ^ and $.
```

Answer (score -2):

you can `cd` to the directory and try the below command:

```
grep ^.......$ *
```

- `.` --> any single character (so seven `.` is seven characters)
- `*` (asterisk) --> all the files in the current directory (except, usually, those whose names begin with a literal `.`). You can give the file name(s) too if preferred.

Comment: As explained in [steeldriver's answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/911207/527764), this will not work because all lines with more than seven characters will also match.